# Update entity class in ASP.NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created the model from existing database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core.

Here is the model of the `Market` table

```
public partial class Market
{
        public Guid MarketId { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string CityF { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string NameF { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

However, I have change the `MarketId` datatype to `int` in the database. Now I want to update the model.

Found some link but this link create the entire model again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

How can I update the model without the creating new model and using the connection string in `appsettings.json`?

Comment: You can use  `Scaffold-DbContext` command with `-force` flag. This way you can  force scaffolding to overwrite existing model files.

Comment: why not just change `MarketId` to `int`?

Comment: Manually changing is not the best option.

Comment: @sanket - can  you please provide me the example

Comment: @sanjaisy this is sample command - `Scaffold-DbContext "<ConnectionString>" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -t <tablename> -f` replace ConnectionString & tablename

Comment: Also note, you will need to do this anytime you make a change in the DB like column added or removed or changed... When you force a scaffold update you will loose any modification you have made to the model file not that I can think of why anyone would do that.

Comment: @sanjaisy Did u tried with Scaffold-DbContext command?

Comment: @Sanket - Yes it worked thanks

Comment: @sanjaisy great :) but if you come across any other option please do share here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To Update entire dbcontext use the below command. link for more details

["Build failed" on Database First Scaffold-DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961115/build-failed-on-database-first-scaffold-dbcontext/40322226#40322226)

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=(local);Database=DefenderRRCart;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir RRStoreContext.Models -context RRStoreContext -Project RR.DataAccess -force
```

To update from Azure Connection and local Connection

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=<Server Name>,1433;Initial Catalog=<Database Name>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<user id>;Password=<password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entity -context <Context Name> -Project <project Name> -force
```

To create the new Context

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=<Server Name>,1433;Initial Catalog=<Database Name>;Persist Security Info=False;
        User ID=<User Id>;Password=<Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection
        Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir <Dir Name>
```

Comment: How is this the correct answer? The questions is about updating a single Entity, the answer updates the entire dbContext.

Comment: @phifi - Yes, you are correct it doesn't update the single entity It just replaces the single entity along with other entities.

Comment: Looks like your initial question is tracked as a feature request for EF here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/831 Maybe you want to add this to your answer?

Answer (score 47):

One option is-

You can use `Scaffold-DbContext` command with `-force` flag. This way you can force scaffolding to overwrite existing model files.

sample command -

```
Scaffold-DbContext "<ConnectionString>" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -t <tablename> -f
```

Replace ConnectionString & TableName as per your requirements.

Comment: This really helped Thanks

Comment: This also works in ASP.NET Core 2.0. It will automatically generate a context file within the project root, if the context file is elsewhere. However, generated code for the new table can easily be moved from `OnModelCreating` and the extra context removed.

Comment: How to do the same programmatically?

Comment: @SagarPatil You can auto generate a context with: Scaffold-DbContext "Server=tcp:"SomeAzureConnectionString";Initial Catalog=(YoutDataBaseName);User ID=(YourUser);Password=(YourPassword);Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f