# How to update existing model class generated by Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-database-first

Working with ASP.NET CORE EF, I have generated model classes from existing database with following command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver\mydb;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Now my database is changed, for example I added a new column in a table `AppUser`. I don't want to use migrations to keep sync models with database.

I already made changes in database and now I want to update my existing model classes from current database state. Any suggestion how to do this?

Should I delete my existing model classes and regenerate by using the same command `Scaffold-DbContext` or do we have any other way make existing model classes to reflect new changes.

Comment: Yes. In general, every time you change your database, you just re-run `Scaffold-DbContext`. You should not directly modify any of the entity classes that are generated, as a result.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt, Same command did the job, just with extra parameter "-f " as mentioned in Julian's answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233300/update-entity-class-in-asp-net-core-entity-framework)?

As far as I know, to update the model you must execute the same command to overwrite the changes but with another additional flag.

I remember using the -f (force) option to overwrite the changes:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver\mydb;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f
```

Although it is also possible to indicate which entity you want to update (table):

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver\mydb;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -t <table> -f
```

Comment: Thanks @Julian, First command done the job. Second command also works but  not as I was expecting. Although it has generated model class for one table but also it overwrites my DbContext class, where it contains DbSet<T> property for only one particular table. It removes remaining properties for other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffold-DbContext can be used with option -Context to expand the current DbContext file, instead of creating a new one.

Example:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=server;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f -Context MyDbContext
```

The generated code for the MyDbContext will be placed on a partial class file.