# Adding Entity Framework Model on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with.Net 6.0, I installed Entity Framework 6.4.4 after adding it when I create an Entity Framework model. I am getting a Popup message saying that.

> The project's target framework does not contain Entity Framework runtime assemblies. Please review the target framework information on the project's property page.

Can somebody tell us how to solve that problem?
[image]

Comment: You are using `Entity Framework 6.4.4` you should be using `Entity Framework Core 6.0.1`

Comment: Sir, I used that too but it's not working keep saying with the same popup message. 
(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.1)

Comment: No, you are not, because Entity Framework Core doesn’t have the ability to add Entity Model, the way you do it. Entity Framework Core only supports code first approach. eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: Sir can you tell me step by step procedure
1. New Projects-->Console Application-->install Package from NugetPackage Manager
2. Entity Framework anyone from this v(6.4.4),v(6.1.3), core
3. Solution explorer select project right click add item
4. New Item data-->Ado.net Entity Data Model

Comment: Can you tell me What that popup massage suggests?

Comment: Thank you, sir, I got the Answer
We have to use .net below 5.0v

Comment: This is a common cause of confusion. The last version of .Net Framework is 4.8 - this is what you should be using with Entity Framework. After that .Net Core 1.0 to 3.2 and .Net 5 & 6 (The "Core" got dropped in an effort to make it seem like all use "Entity Framework Core". That "Core" bit is really important and often gets overlooked (it's the same for ASP.Net and ASP.Net Core)

Comment: Step 3 and 4 should NOT be used at all, when you want to use .net 6, because as I said it prior it is unsupported, as you figured it out yourself, if you want to use this, for whatever reasoning, you will have to use .net framework 4.x and not .net 5.x or .net 6.x. BUT I would strongly recommend to not go this path, use .net 6.x and use Entity Framework Core 6.0.1, and write the models yourself in the so called `code first` approach. DO NOT USE THE USER INTERFACE to create the model, WRITE THE CODE YOURSELF.

Comment: Im sure the database boys absolutely LOVE this one!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install .Net Framework 4.8.

**.Net Core 1 - 3.2 & .Net 5 & 6 has no Entity Framework Data Model available with EF Core**.

You want to use EF 6 (not Core) and Data Model you have to use .Net Framework 4.8 or lower than that.

Comment: Entity Framework Visual Designer
https://msawczyn.github.io/EFDesigner/index.html
Entity Framework Visual Editor
Entity Framework visual editor for EF6, EFCore and beyond.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=michaelsawczyn.EFDesigner2022#:~:text=This%20Visual%20Studio%202022%20extension,visual%20design%20of%20persistent%20classes.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have Target Framework as show.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this to generate/update entire `DbContext` and models:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=(local);Database=DefenderRRCart;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir RRStoreContext.Models -context RRStoreContext -Project RR.DataAccess -force
```

See this post for more info.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413291/4588756