# Net Core Entity Database 1st - Build Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am getting a build error an I know exactly why... **It's because I deleted the old files for entity except for replacing them... with -f**

But that super annoying because now I have to comment out the lines that reference the context... **Is there a option or way to have the scaffolding disregard if there is a build error or not.**

["Build failed" on Database First Scaffold-DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961115/build-failed-on-database-first-scaffold-dbcontext)

Reference ^

Thanks.

EDIT:
Long story short, I now need to comment out manually every reference of my data context in my code and re-scaffold the database because now I get build errors.

EDIT2: 
Was working before but now with the following scaffolg statement it doesn't handle the - in my project name...(Project name: POSI_Master-API) It used to replace -API with _API

> Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=aserver;Initial Catalog=PositiveUsers;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=PositiveConnector;Password=apassword" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Databases/PositiveUser -f

Answer (score 0):

Just restore/revert lost files from your version control system (Git, etc)