# Scaffold Views with Scaffold-DbContext from SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, .net-5, scaffolding

I have tried to scaffold two views from a database in a SQL Server. Code in .Net 5.0.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "conn-string" 
     Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
     -OutputDir Entities -ContextDir . 
     -Context MyContext -UseDatabaseNames -Force 
     -NoPluralize -NoOnConfiguring -Tables View1,View2
```

This runs without error but no entities for this views are generated and I get a message:

> Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table 'View1'.
>
> Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table 'View2'.

How do I use `Scaffold-DbContext` to get these two views?

Comment: Add the schema to the name: dbo.View1,dbo.View2

Comment: Thanks. I had that. But you made me look again and it was a copy/paste problem. Wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from referencing the db schema, you could be stuck with this error because the actual project itself does not compile.

I commented out all the code associated to the `DbContext` model, and ran the following equivalent Scaffold command.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=MyServer;Database=myDb;user=theUser;password=thePwd;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -ContextDir . -Context MyContext -UseDatabaseNames -Force -NoPluralize -NoOnConfiguring -Tables <<your database view>>
```

The command ran successfully and created my class in the root folder. I then moved it into my `Models` folder and went from there. That is optional of course.

There is more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961115/build-failed-on-database-first-scaffold-dbcontext) as to why you need to make sure the solution compiles *before* you run the scaffold command.